# Is there formula for Infix to postix?

Tags: java, computer-science

Hi can i ask some help?is there formula for infix to postfix?...I don't know how to convert them and to give the postfix expression and the postfix evaluation...
for example this 1*2(5+2)-9/6.

Comment: Did you check our textbook? I remember an early CS course asking us to do a similar conversion, and the algorithm was outlined in our textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this procedure to convert from `infix` to `postfix`:

```
Define a stack
Go through each character in the string
If it is between 0 to 9, append it to output string.
If it is left brace push to stack
If it is operator *+-/ then 
    If the stack is empty push it to the stack
    If the stack is not empty then start a loop:
            If the top of the stack has higher precedence
            Then pop and append to output string
            Else break
        Push to the stack

If it is right brace then
    While stack not empty and top not equal to left brace
    Pop from stack and append to output string
    Finally pop out the left brace.

If there is any input in the stack pop and append to the output string.
```

[Take a read here for a better understanding on the procedure with diagrams.](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm)

Comment: what about the postfix evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the expression in different notations one way of doing this would be to use a Binary tree and use pre-/in-/post-order traversal for conversion.